# Enable circular scrolling

Tags: xorg, synaptics-touchpad

I'm trying to enable circular scrolling in my touchpad with synaptics, but something is preventing me of doing so. My `50-synaptics.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TouchpadOff" "0"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "2"
    Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "off"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
    Option "CircScrollTrigger" "0"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "off"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "VertScrollDelta" "-108"
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-108"
EndSection
```

I've tried commenting the vert/horiz scrolling lines out, but didn't work.
How can I make it work? Because the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Circular_Scrolling) says it's correct.

Comment: Are you sure you're using synaptics and not xf86-input-libinput?

Comment: @grawity: yes, I'm sure, the installed one is `xf86-input-synaptics`.